# What is best-practice for the "base" IRI in Turtle -- @base, empty prefix, or named prefix?

Tags: syntax, rdf, turtle-rdf

I am confused about which of these three syntaxes I should use for the home/base IRI.

One would think that using `@base` is preferred, yet that is the only one of the three that I have not seen used in any example.

> NOTE: `@base` provides a prefix for relative IRIs using `<...>`.
>         So in the example below,
>         `<Entity>` expands to `<http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#Entity>`.

Below I mixed all three of them (note the first 3 lines of the file).

```
@base          <http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#> .
@prefix :      <http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#> .
@prefix ent:   <http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix dc:    <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .


# Ontology

<http://my-url.com/ontologies/0.1/entity>
  a owl:Ontology ;
  dc:title "MyEntity"@en ;
  dc:description "A definition of some kind of abstract entity"@en .


# Classes

<Entity>
  a owl:Class ;
  rdfs:label "Entity" ;
  rdfs:comment "My kind of entity." .

:Author
  a owl:Class ;
  rdfs:label "Entity" ;
  rdfs:comment "My kind of entity." .


# Properties

# Each entity must have exactly one author
ent:author
  a owl:ObjectProperty ;
  rdfs:domain :Entity ;
  rdfs:range <Author> ;
  owl:cardinality 1 .
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no single "best practice" for this.

All of these conform to the [Turtle 1.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/).

You can use whichever you prefer.

That said, in my experience, most Turtle authors choose not to use `@base` per se, and instead use a mix of named and unnamed `@prefix` according to how they expect their document to be shared and/or reused -- with named `@prefix` generally being used in an effort to improve human comprehension, and unnamed generally being used to save typing and/or filesize.